# Angular UI select2 - shows [object Object] on tab switch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-select2, ui-select2

select2 with Angular seems to be working - however I'm using ui-router and I have different tabs.

One of my select2 inputs is used in two tabs and the ng-model is the same. While everything works, when I switch from one tab to the other, rather than showing the value in the select2 input, it shows [object Object], even if I switch from Tab A to Tab B and then Tab A again, instead of seeing the value I put down, I see [object Object]

Is there an easy fix for this?

The code is as follows:

```
// In the parent controller 

$scope.select2Options = { allowClear:true, multiple:true, tags:[] } ;
$scope.select2InclTables = []; // whether I set this or not, the problem still remains

$scope.$watch('select2InclTables', function() {
  $scope.tables = "";
  if ($scope.select2InclTables) {
      for (var i =0; i<$scope.select2InclTables.length; i++) {
         $scope.tables+="`"+$scope.select2InclTables[i].text;
     }
 }
});



//In both tabs (two separate html files) : 

<input ui-select="select2Options" ng-model="$parent.select2InclTables" data-placeholder="Pick tables"/>
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your directive?

Comment: @Florent just did :-)

Comment: What's the value of `$parent.select2InclTables`?